# Call Jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a Jquery function like the following

```
function myFunction(){  
            $.messager.show({  
                title:'My Title',  
                msg:'The message content',  
                showType:'fade',  
                style:{  
                    right:'',  
                    bottom:''  
                }  
            });  
        }
```

If certain condition is true, I would like to invoke `myFunction` and a popup message will display. How can I call myFunction? so that it will be something like onClick().

Comment: It's a JavaScript function, not a jQuery function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To call the function on click of some html element (control).

```
$('#controlID').click(myFunction);
```

You will need to ensure you bind the event when your html element is ready on which you binding the event. You can put the code in document.ready

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#controlID').click(myFunction);
});
```

You can use anonymous function to bind the event to the html element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#controlID').click(function(){
         $.messager.show({  
            title:'My Title',  
            msg:'The message content',  
            showType:'fade',  
            style:{  
                right:'',  
                bottom:''  
            }  
        });  
    });
});
```

If you want to bind click with many elements you can use class selector

```
$('.someclass').click(myFunction);
```

**Edit** based on comments by OP, If you want to call function under some condition

You can use if for conditional execution, for example,

```
if(a == 3)
     myFunction();
```

Comment: Adil, I have put it wringly I guess, I would want to call the function not any click event, but when a condtion is true I would like to call the function.

Comment: You can use if for conditional execution, for example, if(a == 3) myFunction();

Answer (score 5):

calling a function is simple ..

```
 myFunction();
```

so your code will be something like..

```
 $(function(){
     $('#elementID').click(function(){
         myFuntion();  //this will call your function
    });
 });

  $(function(){
     $('#elementID').click( myFuntion );

 });
```

or with some condition

```
if(something){
   myFunction();  //this will call your function
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add click event by jquery in $(document).ready() like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

                  $('#YourControlID').click(function(){
                     if(Check your condtion)
                     {
                             $.messager.show({  
                                title:'My Title',  
                                msg:'The message content',  
                                showType:'fade',  
                                style:{  
                                    right:'',  
                                    bottom:''  
                                }  
                            });  
                     }
                 });
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#YourControlID').click(function(){
        if() { //your condition
            $.messager.show({  
                title:'My Title',  
                msg:'The message content',  
                showType:'fade',  
                style:{  
                    right:'',  
                    bottom:''  
                }  
            });  
        }
    });
});
```