# querying javascript through html

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I have a .js file and a .html file, I want the html document to get data from the .js file and manipulate it to produce a pie chart. How should I proceed with it?

Currently, I have a function in the .js file . I would like to call it from within html  command.

EDIT:
I have the charts ready in html and have queried the database in js. I am left with linking them. I want to display a pie charts based on data values in mssql database

This is my html file index12.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  <script> </script>

<style>

    rect{                                              
        stroke-width: 2;                                          
        }  
    .legend{                                                
         stroke:black;
         opacity:1; 
         font-size: 12px; 
         }

    text{                                               
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        fill:black;
        }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>hi how  ru</p>
<div id="chart"></div>
  <button type="button">Change Content</button>
 <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js></script>

      <script src="d3/d3.js"></script>
      <select id ="slctmodel"></select>
      <script>
      var dataset;
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("app.js", success = function (data) {
              dataset = data;
                                 });

          setTimeout(function () {

              /* dataset = [
                         { "module": "A", "errors": 50 },
                         { "module": "B", "errors": 120 },
                         { "module": "C", "errors": 10 },
                         { "module": "D", "errors": 200 },
                         { "module": "E", "errors": 27 },
                         { "module": "F", "errors": 25 },
                         { "module": "G", "errors": 40 }
               ];*/
              console.log(dataset);
              var width = 1500;                                  
              var height = 1500;
              var radius = 150;

              var legendRectSize = 16;                           
              var legendSpacing = 4;                              
              console.log("hi1");
              var color = d3.scale.ordinal()                         
                    .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", ])
                    .range(["#FFEBAA", "#EEAB79", "#955C52", "#BE4C60",
                         "#B42E61", "#851362", "#5E0063"]);
              var svg = d3.select('#chart')                      
                    .append('svg')
                    .attr('width', width)
                    .attr('height', height)
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + 850 + ',' + 250+')');

              d3.select('#chart svg')                                    
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("x", 850)
                    .attr("y", 30)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .text("PROBABILITY OF FAILURE IN MODULES");      

              var arc = d3.svg.arc()                                     
                    .innerRadius(30)
                    .outerRadius(radius);

              var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()                         
                    .innerRadius(20)
                    .outerRadius(radius + 30);
              console.log("hi2");
              var pie = d3.layout.pie()                      
                    .value(function (d) { return d.errors; })
                    .sort(null);                             
              var path = svg.selectAll('path')               
                    .data(pie(dataset))
                    .enter()
                    .append('path')
                    .attr('d', arc)
                    .attr('fill', function (d, i) {
                        return color(d.data.module);
                    })
                    .attr("opacity", 1)
                    .attr("stroke", "black")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                    .on("mouseenter", function (d) {             
                        d3.select(this)
                      .attr("stroke", "black")
                      .transition()
                      .duration(1000)
                      .attr("d", arcOver)
                      .attr("stroke-width", 4)
                      .attr("opacity", 1)
                    })
                    .on("mouseleave", function (d) {         
                        d3.select(this).transition()
                       .attr("d", arc)
                       .attr("stroke", "black")
                       .attr("stroke-width", 2)
                       .attr("opacity", 1);
                    })
              console.log("hi3");
              svg.selectAll('text')
                  .data(pie(dataset))
                  .enter()
                  .append('text')
                  .attr("transform", function (d) {      
                      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
                  })
                  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function (d) {
                      return d.value;
                  })
                  .style("pointer-events", "none");



              var legend = svg.selectAll('.legend')                 
                    .data(color.domain())
                    .enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'legend')
                    .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
                        var height = legendRectSize + legendSpacing;
                        var offset = height * color.domain().length / 2;

                        var vert = i * height - offset;
                        return 'translate(' + 250 + ',' + vert + ')';
                    });
              console.log("hi4");
              legend.append('rect')                                     
                    .attr('width', legendRectSize)
                    .attr('height', legendRectSize)
                    .style('fill', color)
                    .style('stroke', color);

              legend.append('text')                                     
                    .attr('x', legendRectSize + legendSpacing)
                    .attr('y', legendRectSize - legendSpacing)
                    .text(function (d) { return d; });

              console.log("hi5");
          }
      , 500);

 });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

AND MY APP.JS FILE IS

```
var http = require('http');                         //connect with http
var sql = require('mssql');                         //connect with sql
var express = require('express');                   //connect with express
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var jQ = require('jquery');
env: {
browser: true
 }

var Connection = sql.Connection;
var Request = sql.Request;

var a; var recordSet;

var config = {
server: '10.2.13.211',                          //my IP address - obtained        
//server: '.',
database: 'trialdb',                            //my table is within this      
user: 'sa',                                     //windows authentication           
password: 'admin123#',
port: 1433                                      //deafault port number
};

function send404Response(response) {
response.writeHead(404, { "Context-Type": "text/plain" });                                   
response.write("Error 404:Page not found");
response.end();                                                                
}

function loadEmployees() {                                                          

var dbConn = new sql.Connection(config);

dbConn.connect().then(function () {                                             

    var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);

    request.query("select * from list").then(function (recordSet) {         
        //  console.log(recordSet);
        a = recordSet[1].errors;
        return recordSet;
        dbConn.close();                                                      //close connection
    }).catch(function (err) {

        console.log(err);
        dbConn.close();
    });
}).catch(function (err) {

    console.log(err);
});


}


app.use(express.static('D:/d3 project/project_part1/project_part1/'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../index12.html'));
//res.send(recordSet);
});


app.get('/abt', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../startpage.html'));
});

function onRequest(request, response) {
if (request.method == 'GET' && request.url == '/') {
    console.log("user made a request" + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, { "Context-Type": "text/plain" });
    loadEmployees();
    setTimeout(function () {
        // response.write("here is some data");
        response.write("hiya" + a);
        response.end();
    }
        , 200);
}
else {
    send404Response(response); console.log('error 404');
}
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);                                         
console.log('server will run on requset to port 8888');
var server = app.listen(8081);
```

My 'data' variable in the jquery part of index12.html file has an undefined value.It should have the value of 'recordSet' variable in the app.js file

How do I proceed with it?

How do I call the function loadEmployees() of app.js in index12.html so that I can store the value returned by the function loadEmployees() i.e, the 'recordSet' in the 'data' variable of index12.html

Comment: Form your question, I understand that you just want to accces that JS in html, just write a `<script>` tag and access it what is the issue there.. If the issue is in drawing the chart then you can refer @afuc's answer

Comment: if within my <script> tags of html, I access the methods declared & defined in js, it doesnt work ... the functions are locally defined

Comment: can you please share the code and tell me what are you trying to achieve.?

Comment: You need jquery/javascript to modify html dom elements.Share code so that it would be clear what you are trying to achieve. You need to feed the response data to the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chart.js library to create charts on html.

refer http://www.chartjs.org/

Comment: I have the charts ready on html and I have queried the mssql database in js.. I want to link them

Comment: How have you made the chart? If you just want to access js variable in html, refer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845710/javascript-variable-access-in-html

Comment: I already have a <script src="d3/d3.js"> tag, how can I add another jquery src tag

Comment: Add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` for jQuery.

Comment: yes, I did that and now, I need to call a function and not the whole file?Is it possible>

Comment: [Call jQuery func](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15918610/call-jquery-function)

Comment: Yes,I used jquery ajax for the question and it worked fine. Thank you